# Chrome developer tools not displaying full html/js file

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I see an error in the console view. I click on the line number, and it opens the HTML file in the sources tab. But that line is not displayed because only the first 11 lines of the HTML file (which is mainly JS) are shown. This is a recurring problem for me. The full file  is loaded and successfully parsed and executed by the browser, when I view the file in the browser the full source is there. If I load the page before opening the developer console everything works as expected. What might be happening?

Version 37.0.2062.44 beta-m

Comment: It sounds like a bug of the Chrome Developer tools. My suggestion is to report it in the Google Chromium bug tracker. You can find details on how to do that at http://dev.chromium.org/for-testers/bug-reporting-guidelines

Comment: Thanks: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=398600

Comment: This should be fixed in Chrome 38.